# fstab not mounting VirtualBox shared folder?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, fstab

I have a virtual machine here which I use for development, so as not to mess anything up in my existing environment.

I've made a share named "web" available to the guest OS (Ubuntu 12.10 Server) from the host OS (Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop). I have configured it to automatically mount in `/etc/fstab` with the following line:

```
web    /var/www    vboxsf    defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000    0    0
```

However, when I reboot, it's definitely not mounted, the `/var/www` folder shows the default install's `index.html` file, not the contents of the shared folder.

If I run `sudo mount`, I see the mount in the output:

```
web on /var/www type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=1000,rw)
web on /media/sf_web type vboxsf (gid=1001,rw)
```

It seems to also be mounted in a different location which I didn't setup.

If I try to remount all the mounts in `/etc/fstab` by running `sudo mount -a`, it still is not mounted.

I can only get it mounted by manually mounting it using `mount`. Where is this other mount location coming from and why is what I'm doing not working?

Comment: Future referece; for me i totally had the path wrong, i had added vboxfs in the modules, not sure if thats needed now for me, but make sure you do this as well.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, I had "auto-mount" enabled in VirtualBox configuration for the instance. This messes with things, so I simply added my user to the `vboxsf` group (in addition to `www-data`) and pointed Apache to `/media/sf_web`.

Comment: same issue for centos7 with latest version of VirtualBox - a bug to raise on their github maybe? Either way this is a correct solution for it :)

Comment: Alternatively you can turn off auto-mount, which is what I did. But this provided the clue, so thanks.