# Failed to mount /media/sf_vagrant

Tags: debian, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to setup automated mounting of my vbox shared folders. Everything works just fine from my normal user:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf vagrant /media/sf_vagrant
```

However if I follow the manual from upstream [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_manual), then I cannot even reboot. systemd report an error in `Unit media-sf_vagrant.mount`. The message states `Failed to mount /media/sf_vagrant`.

Here is the line I added to fstab (per upstream doc):

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
[...]
vagrant   /media/sf_vagrant   vboxsf   defaults  0   0
```

If that matter I am using a debian testing (stretch) on amd64 (aka Debian 8). And the window manager is `Xfce`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not clear why the official documentation does not work for me. But I found the solution reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68634/32896).

The solution is a simple one liner on debian:

```
$ sudo adduser <user> vboxsf
```

Simple replace `<user>` with your actual user name, and then *reboot*.

On fedora:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf <user>
```